# The square root of a positive semidefinite matrix​

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetry, positive-semidefinite

I am confused about the concept semidefinite matrix:

Why all the eigenvalues of $A = B^t . B$ are non-negative? My thought is that:
  $$X . (A . X) 
= X . ((B^t . B) . X)
= X . (B^t . (B . X))
= (B . X) . (B . X) 
= (|B.X|)^2 $$ 
Because $(|B.X|)^2$ cannot be negative, $X . (A . X) \ge 0$ no matter what $X$ is. But I am not sure how the fact of $X . (A . X) >= 0$ is related to $A.X=eigenvalue[A].X$ and is therefore related to that all eigenvalues of A are non-negative.

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: I"m sorry but I have never seen neither the words "hanger" and "aligner" frames, nor the word "stretcher"

Comment: Have you seen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) ?